# Prove that $\log(n) = O(\sqrt{n})$

Tags: asymptotics

How to prove $\log(n) = O(\sqrt{n})$?

How do I find the $c$ and the $n_0$?

I understand to start, I need to find something that $\log(n)$ is smaller to, but I m having a hard time coming up with the example.

Comment: Hint: consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: @Anson Can you write your own solution and accept it so that this question gets an answer?
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/what-to-do-if-you-figure-out-the-answer-to-your-own-question

Answer (score 61):

Less sophisticated: $\log(x) < x$ for all $x > 0$ (as is easily seen from its integral representation).  Therefore $\log(x) = 2 \log \sqrt{x} < 2 \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: how'd you get $2\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @Yangfan Substitute $x\leftarrow \sqrt{x}$ in $\log(x) < x$.

Comment: Can you explain this for non-math guys but programmers too?  Thanks in advance1

Comment: Just replace $x$ with $(\sqrt{x})^2$. The exponent becomes the multiplier of the logarithm.

Answer (score 8):

You want $c > 0$ and $n_0$ such that $\log n \le c \sqrt{n}$ for $n > n_0$. Actually any $c > 0$ would work, the only problem is to find $n_0$.  Alternatively, any $n_0 > 0$ would work if we find the right $c$, and if we have the freedom to choose this might be a better option because it's easier to solve for $c$ than to solve for $n$.  The inequality says 
$c \ge \dfrac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}$.  Note that $$\dfrac{d}{dn} \dfrac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}} =  \dfrac{2-\log n}{2 n^{3/2}}$$
so $\log (n)/\sqrt{n}$ is increasing for $n \le e^2$ and decreasing for $n \ge e^2$.  Thus we could take $c = \log(e^2)/\sqrt{e^2} = 2/e \approx .7357588824$ which would work for all $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 6):

$\log(x)  < \sqrt{x}$ for all $x>0$ because  $\log(x)  /\sqrt{x}$ has a single maximum value $2/e<1$ (at $x=e^2$).

Answer (score -5):

consider n=2^100

then log(n)=Log(2^100)

```
           =100*log2
           =100
```

and now apply this to sqrt(n)

then Sqrt(n)=sqrt(2^100)

```
           =2^50
```

we can clearly say that sqrt(n) is larger then logn.

Comment: Use Mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for math edidting